# Homeomorphism - transforming mug into donut

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I read that a map is 'visually' a homeomorphism if you don't have to fold or tear the object. Thus, I was wondering what the problem with folding is? 
I guess that in this statement they don't assume the classical procedure of folding, but more or less a superposition where you merge different parts of the object?

Also, I have a question regarding this homeomorphism where the donut is transformed into a mug. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)

Why is taking the volume out of the filled mug different from reducing a line to a cylinder?

From my experience I would say that a line is not homeomorphic to a cylinder, but it is also just some sort of extension, as is filling the mug or taking some volume out of it?

EDIT: In the comments it was suggested that a mug that is closed at the bottom and at the top is homeomorphic to a mug that is just closed at the bottom.

Now if you think about this in a plane, then the two things are clearly different, as the first one has a trivial fundamental group and the latter one a fundamental group that is given by the integers(due to homeomorphy to the circle). Thus, I still don't understand why moving an additional layer up to the top is a homeomorphism?
[image]

Comment: Folding say, a square

$$\lVert (x,y)\rVert_\infty\le 1$$

by the map

$$(x,y)\mapsto (x,|y|)$$

in half would mean that the function is 2-1 most places, which contradicts the injectivity of a homeomorphism.

The torus example is not removing volume, the bottom of the mug is being brought to the top by just stretching the skin, the inside is still empty. A line and a cylinder are **not** homeomorphic, so there's no problem there.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so does this imply that the mug that is closed at the bottom(as every mug is) is homeomorphic to a mug that is closed at the bottom and at the top?

Comment: Well, the thing about the bottom is, it's really just a crunched down top, it's two thin layers, one above the other, with nothing in between, turning it into a torus means you've inflated that empty space. to push the top part of what was geographically near the bottom (but not equal to it) up higher, so that animation is a bit misleading. It's easier to see with pictures, but I cannot include those, sorry. :-(

Comment: could you explain the difference between this idea and my drawing in the question?

Comment: Ah yes, I can. It does not. The mug closed at the top is a different object, it's basically a sphere glued to a torus if all you're doing is putting a cap on it.

Comment: sorry for my stupid question, but I have still some difficulties with it: You say that the top layer and the bottom layer are initially close together but not equal. This sounds strange in the sense that it is similar to the standard notion of infinitesimal distances which is hardly rigorous. Also, I have troubles to understand the geometric difference between my 2d drawing and the procedure of putting a cap on my mug. Could you just try to explain a little bit more where the difference is between my object and the mug? sorry, for these many question, but I would love to understand this.

Comment: I've found a way to get a picture, take a look at it, and we can continue this in the comments on the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, a post with an image. I'll keep all of my comments included in here to avoid having many cross references.

Firstly, folding, as I said in my comment the map on the box

$$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : \lVert (x,y)\rVert_\infty\le 1\}$$

can be folded in half via

$$(x,y)\mapsto (x,|y|)$$

which is not injective, hence not a homeomorphism.

For the mug to donut question, we have the picture of the mug. As they mean it, even though visually you cannot see the hollow inside. This is depicted below in a cross-section, so you can see the empty space. Also, I've colored the corresponding part you're having issues with red so it is more explicit where things are going and *which* part of the bottom becomes the top. Notice there is just more empty space in the middle, so we're inflating it, not really "filling" it with anything.

[image: cup to torus]

Notice how the first mug has the empty space between the bottom of the inside and the bottom of the outside. It's that part that gets lifted up to the top of the mug, NOT a whole new cap added.

Additionally, if you have an *actual* cap added, you get the same old object, only with a sphere glued on, as illustrated here

[image: sphere cap]

Comment: ah thank you that helped a lot, so the point is that this is really a 'double layer'. thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly right. :-)

Comment: @TobiasHurth You can also view it as a single layer, the "empty space" being filled with "rubber" that is expanded as much as necessary.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut is right, but if that confuses you at all, you can also ignore it that fact (no offense J-C, purely pedagogical advice). The geometry of the boundary is what is underpinning the homeomorphism, and it's easier to see how the "bottom" stays the bottom and also "becomes" the top too when you deal with the hollow version. This is because it clearly shows which part goes where (hence my red-coloring).